# Geneos server downtime sampler

Tags: monitoring, geneos

We have a requirement to measure unix server downtime for a month using geneos . We explored some of the plug ins available available in geneos but we were not able to find .

Requirement is geneos sampler should add the total time the unix server went down in month and display result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sampler to check the server downtime.

Considering you have a script (written in bash/perl or any other language for that matter) which is able to generate the required output, you could use such a script in the 'toolkit' plugin in Geneos.

Remember that the script should produce comma separated values as an output along with a header (title) record.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement Gateway monitoring using the "Gateway-probeData" plugin.
This will check that the Gateway can communicate with the Netprobe.

Additionally I have set up a crontab job to check the Netprobe is running

`# Check and restart Netprobes
0,15,30,45 * * * * /script/to/check/all/probes.sh`

Subsequently I would set up dbLogging in the GSE and the Gateway can store the historic data of the connectivity of the Server (via the Netprobe)